# Generalizing the interpretation of a derivative as a fraction

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

Sometimes derivatives are (inappropriately) interpreted and handled as if they were fractions. For instance, when applying a chain rule, $df/dx$ would be handled as if $df$ was the numerator and $dx$ the denominator. Often, though, and especially in simple cases, the results turn out to be the correct ones.

In the same spirit of those uncomfortable practises, is there anything looking like $$\log\frac{df}{dx}=\log df - \log dx$$
that could too (sometimes, somehow) make sense?

Comment: Maybe it would be help if you were to describe how you wanted to use this.

Comment: I didn't give too much thought about how one could take advantage of that "formula", but I guess that it could be in the context of Lie groups and topological spaces, where the logarithm and differential forms are basic ingredients.